# How much statistics knowledge is enough for studying time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references

I am interested in studying time series (both theoretical and applied), my background is in mathematics and my probability knowledge is well enough but I haven't studied stats deeply (only one course in inference);  what is the minimum prerequisite in stats for a good grasp of time series? And generally what mathematics is needed for it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Depends on what aspect you would focus on: time series is a vast topic and researchers rather (unsurprisingly) concentrate on localized topics for study. In any case, knowledge on stochastic process, a bit of functional analysis should suffice to begin a theoretical focussed course.

Comment: A good place to start is Hamilton's time series text and it would provide you an insight as to what things are needed. A lighter introductory read would be that by Chatfield.

Comment: Having learned from both those books (Chatfield and then Hamilton), I am in strong agreement with @User1865345.

Comment: There is not one unified field of time series. My discipline is biostatistics. Some biostats models are completely alien to econometricians, and *vice versa*. There are many accessible texts at the level of a second year post-graduate program. So any decent 1st year probability and statistics course text (like Casella Berger) would cover the right material - i.e. regression, information, exponential families, hypothesis testing.

Comment: I think Sheldon Ross' Probability Models is a great text requiring only 3rd year calculus and builds significant intuition on handling probability - which has an underemphasized role in statistics pedagogy.

Comment: @AdamO what time series book do you use in your research/work ?